# Method in onCreate runs only after device rotation

Tags: android, loader, asynctaskloader

My `Activity` uses `RecyclerView` to show a list of data. This data downloads some `Moview`s using a `AsyncTaskLoader`. I initialise the loader in `onCreate` but when I run it I see nothing. But if I click the button to rotate the device I see data. I tried to put this method to other lifecycle methods, but still the same. And logs are the same all the time.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie);

    mMovieListRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_movieList);
    mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    mMovieListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
    mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Movie>());
    mMovieListRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
    initialiseLoader();
}

private void initialiseLoader() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
        loaderManager.initLoader(MOVIE_LOADER_ID, null,  MovieActivity.this);
    }
```

My loader:

```
public class MovieLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Movie>> {

private static final String LOG_TAG = MovieLoader.class.getName();

private String mURL;

public MovieLoader(Context context, String url) {
    super(context);
    mURL = url;
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    forceLoad();
}

@Override
public List<Movie> loadInBackground() {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mURL)) {
        return null;
    }

    return QueryUtils.fetchMovieData(mURL);
}

    @Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Movie>> loader, List<Movie> data) {
    mMovieAdapter.clear();
    if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
        mMovieAdapter.addAll(data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Movie>> loader) {
    mMovieAdapter.clear();
}
```

Comment: The adapter is being initialized with an emptry ArrayList(), where is that being replaced after the load process is finished?

Comment: are you using mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after asyncTask loaded data?

Comment: After  **mMovieAdapter.addAll(data);** add mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); it will work

Comment: @akshay_shahane
Thanks! It helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Movie>> loader, List<Movie> data) {
    mMovieAdapter.clear();
    if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
        mMovieAdapter.addAll(data);
        mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```